# How do I code up nested derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want expressions for the spherical Bessel functions in terms of sinusoids using Rayleigh's formulae:
$$
j_{n}(x)=(-x)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
y_{n}(x)=-(-x)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}
$$
However, I can't figure out how to code this up using only one (repeated) use of the derivative operator. I'm instead having to resort to nesting them e.g. for $j_{3}$:

```
(-x)^3 D[D[D[(Sin[x]/x),x]/x,x]/x,x]/x
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess `-x D[#,x]/x &`? As in `Nest[-x D[#,x]/x &, Sin[x], n]`?

Comment: But your x's on the numerator and denominator cancel out, simply leaving derivatives of sin(x).

Comment: `Clear[j];  j[n_?IntegerQ, x_] := Simplify[(-x)^n Nest[D[#, z]/z &, Sin[z]/z, n] /. z -> x];
j[3, x] == SphericalBesselJ[3, x] // FullSimplify  (* True *)`

Comment: Thanks LouisB. This does exactly what I want.

Comment: D'oh! Kinda obvious how to fix it, though, no?

Comment: @LouisB:  I don't think you actually need those shenanigans with `z` in there if you want to simplify things a little.  The code seems to work fine without them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["ChainD"](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/ChainD) to do this:

```
j[n_, x_] := Block[{z}, (-2 z)^n ResourceFunction["ChainD"][Sin[z]/z, {z^2, n}]] /. z -> x
```

Then:

```
j[3, x] == SphericalBesselJ[3,x] //FullSimplify
```

> True